# Minimal elevator problem in a building with n floors and k lifts

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

So the problem is:
*"Given an **n** number of floors for a building with **k** lifts, where every lift L<sub>i</sub> goes from a<sub>i</sub> floor to b<sub>i</sub> floor, (a<sub>i</sub> and b<sub>i</sub> are given) find the minimum number of lifts from first to **n**-th floor."*

This problem has to be solved using dynamic programming. The only problem is I don't how to start.
So does anyone have any type of ideas how to start this.

Comment: Is something missing?  The question as stated doesn’t seem to make sense.  Specifically this phrase “*every lift Li goes from a(I) floor to b(i) floor*” is puzzling.  The only inputs given were **n** and **k**, so what are a(i) and b(i) supposed to be?

Comment: What my professor was trying to say for each lift you have a starting point and a destination, like for example lift number 1 goes from 2. floor to 5., floor number 2 goes from 1. floor to 6. floor etc

Comment: The only techinque that we learned so far was Subproblem Overlap.

Comment: Honestly, the question still doesn’t make any sense to me.  Can you provide a simple example input and the correct solution?

Comment: I don't have an example, that's worst, been trying to puzzle this problem for about 4 hours straight

Comment: Ok, so here’s an example: let’s say that **n = 8**, **k = 2* and Lift(1) goes from floor 2 to 4 and Lift(2) goes from floor 4 to 6.  What’s the correct answer that your program is supposed to give?

Comment: in that given example there isn't a lift to reach the 8th floor so the answer would be infinity or -1

Comment: AHH, so the actual question is “*what is the minimum number of lifts*  **needed to get from** *the first floor to the last floor?*”

Comment: yes that sums it up

Comment: Why don't you start by creating a function that accepts parameters? For example, `function MinimalNumberOfLifts(int floors, int lifts) { int minimumNumberOfLifts = //your formula or code here; return minimumNumberOfLifts; }` .

Comment: Can lifts stop at intermediate floors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is quite similar to the [Jumping-Game problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/); except we need to create the input-array ourselves based on the `(ai, bi) values`.

Lets do that first (create the input-array for Jump-game problem):

```
N = 10 ## num of total floors
V = [(1, 5), (2, 8), (4, 10), (9, 10)]

nums = [0 for _ in range(N)] ## array we need to fill up to transform this problem to Jump-Game problem

## nums[i] represents the maximum number of floors it can go from floor-i (starting from floor 0 to floor N-1)

for ab_pair in V:
  a, b = ab_pair
  floor_diff = max(b-a, 0)
  if a >= N or a < 0:
    continue
  nums[a-1] = max(nums[a-1], floor_diff)
```

Now, we just need to solve the Jump-game problem with the above `input-array: nums`.

That is, find the minimum number of jumps required to reach the top-floor:

```
    def jump(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        if len(nums) <= 1:
            return 0
        
        numsteps = 0
        nc = -1
        tc = -1
        for i in range(len(nums)-1):
            if i >= nc:
                numsteps += 1
                nc = max(tc, i+nums[i])
            else:
                tc = max(tc, i+nums[i])
            if nc >= len(nums)-1:
                return numsteps
        
        return -1
```

Output:

```
## For [(1, 5), (2, 8), (4, 10), (9, 10)]

2
```

Comment: @TarikPašić I think you need to add more details to your question so others can understand better. Maybe you can add a thorough example and submit an edit.